# Convert nested array of strings into nested array of doubles using functional programming

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, swift3

I'd like to convert nested array of strings into nested array of doubles

example:

```
let Strings = [["1.1", "1.2"],["2.1", "2.2"]]
```

to

```
let Doubles = [[1.1, 1.2],[2.1, 2.2]]
```

I tried

```
let Doubles = Strings.flatMap(){$0}.flatMap(){Double($0)}
```

but in this case I obtain one array of double values, how to keep this array nested?

**EDIT:**

Could you also elaborate why not using `map()` twice nor `flatMap()` twice? Why the right way to do this is to use `map`, then `flatMap`?

Comment: Note that your code calls two *different* `flatMap()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to sort things out. Array has a [`map()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688519-map) method

```
/// Returns an array containing the results of mapping the given closure
/// over the sequence's elements.
public func map<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

which creates a new array by transforming each element, and a 
[`flatMap()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689578-flatmap) method

```
/// Returns an array containing the non-`nil` results of calling the given
/// transformation with each element of this sequence.
public func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

which is similar but ignores the elements which are mapped to `nil`
by the closure.

And there is another [`flatMap()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689788-flatmap) method

```
/// Returns an array containing the concatenated results of calling the
/// given transformation with each element of this sequence.
public func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Iterator.Element]
```

which transforms each element to a sequence and concatenates the
results.

Your code calls the second `flatMap()` method to flatten the
array to one dimension, and then the first `flatMap()` method to
convert the strings to numbers.

---

The first candidate for transforming arrays (or sequences in general) is `map()`, and that
works for nested arrays as well:

```
let strings = [["1.0", "2.0"],["3.0", "4.0"]]
let doubles = strings.map { $0.map { Double($0) }}
print(doubles) // [[Optional(1.0), Optional(2.0)], [Optional(3.0), Optional(4.0)]]
```

The result is a nested array of *optionals* because the conversion
to a floating point value can fail. How to fix that?

*Forcefully unwrap* (usually not recommended):

```
let strings = [["1.0", "2.0"],["3.0", "4.0"]]
let doubles = strings.map { $0.map { Double($0)! }}
print(doubles) // [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

That is fine if you have *fixed* data and can *guarantee* that 
each string is a valid floating point value. If not, the program
will crash:

```
let strings = [["1.0", "2.0"],["3.0", "wot?"]]
let doubles = strings.map { $0.map { Double($0)! }}
// fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

*Provide a default value:*

```
let strings = [["1.0", "2.0"],["3.0", "wot?"]]
let doubles = strings.map { $0.map { Double($0) ?? 0.0 }}
print(doubles) // [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 0.0]]
```

Here the invalid string is mapped to `0.0`, so that the "shape"
of the array is preserved. But `0.0` is a "magic number" now,
and we cannot see from the result if it comes from a valid
or an invalid string.

*Ignore invalid strings.* And now `flatMap()` comes into play
(the first version):

```
let strings = [["1.0", "2.0"],["3.0", "wot?"]]
let doubles = strings.map { $0.flatMap { Double($0) }}
print(doubles) // [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0]]
```

The inner `flatMap()` returns an array of the non-nil
`Double($0)` values, i.e. all invalid strings are ignored.

Advantage: The code cannot crash due to invalid input,
and no "magic numbers" are used.
Possible disadvantage: The array shape is not preserved.

So pick your choice!

Comment: omg, this is just a flawless explanation, you are incredible. Btw, how can you tell which flatMap() did I call, since both works on arrays?

Comment: @DCDC: Command-click it in the Xcode source code editor – or just "see" it :)

Comment: yeah ok, but why different methods are called ? :P

Comment: @DCDC: It depends on the receiver and on the closure. The second closure `{Double($0)}` returns an optional. The first closure `{$0}` returns an array.

Answer (score 2):

In the first transformation you should use map instead of flatMap like the following:

`let doubles = Strings.map { $0.flatMap {Double($0)} }`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
let doubles = strings.map { $0.flatMap { Double($0) } }
```

One suggestion variable name always start with lower case so instead of `Doubles` and `Strings` write like `doubles` and `strings` .

Answer (score 1):

Given this

```
let strings = [["1.1", "1.2"], ["2.1", "2.2"]]
```

You can write

```
let doubles: [[Double]] = strings.map { elms -> [Double] in
    return elms.flatMap { Double($0) }
}
```

### Shorter version

If you want a shorter  version (slightly different from the other answers) then

```
let doubles = strings.map { $0.flatMap(Double.init) }
```